# What is the equivalent function for " cvWriteFrame " to use Mat - image type?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, writer, iplimage

What is the equivalent function for " cvWriteFrame " to use Mat - image type ?

In IplImage it can be done using like below:

```
CvVideoWriter *writer;
IplImage* frame = " IMAGE ";   

cvWriteFrame(writer, frame);
```

How to write video for Mat Files.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Opencv doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)

```
C++: VideoWriter& VideoWriter::operator<<(const Mat& image)
C++: void VideoWriter::write(const Mat& image)
Python: cv2.VideoWriter.write(image) → None
C: int cvWriteFrame(CvVideoWriter* writer, const IplImage* image)
Python: cv.WriteFrame(writer, image) → int
```

So i guess something like

```
cv::Mat image;
....
cv::VideoWriter writer;
writer.open(...);
if (writer.isOpened())
  writer << image;
```